# Why are relationships limited to two degrees?

Tags: relationships

I have a structure in which an umbrella organization has a few dozen clubs which have members. And it has some departments some of the members have a relation to.

Now if I would want one of the admins to have some access to information in the departments, I would have to add the department as a relationship with the proper access rights. This is a tedious job and might lead to faults. I would like to have an intermediate level grouping and departments, but then I am limited to the two degrees[image]

I have tried to draw a picture.

Comment: You could use groups for access control? Doesn't have to be purely relationships.

Comment: perhaps i do not understand but Permissioned Relationship extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls does let it go multiple layers

Comment: Thanks, @petednz-fuzion. I think that will fit perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I will add my answer as an Answer.

The [Permissioned Relationship](http://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension does let it go multiple layers

Answer (score 0):

The "why" question is fairly straightforward in an open source, community supported and community developed software world: because so far no one wanted more levels badly enough to develop or fund the development of an extensions for it :-)

But I would certainly recommend playing with the extension that @petednz recommended, and check if you can achieve your requirements.

And obviously you are very welcome to develop/fund the development of an extension that introduces more levels.

Comment: I was faintly aware of the open source, community supported and community developed software environment. ;-)  I just wanted to check whether there were grave architectural issues when this would be developed. But I am very happy with @petednz-fusion's answer.